# Subquerying in mysql with full-text querying

Tags: mysql, perl, full-text-search, subquery

I am trying to query a database. I already have a file that includes some primary keys out of this whole database. Now I want to filter these primary keys and get only those primary keys which also agree to "other condition". My primary keys are associated to abstracts in the database. The abstracts are full-text indexed. Now I want to consider the abstracts using the given primary keys, look for my "other condition(terms)" in those abstracts and if its present I want to pull their primary keys out(which is going to be same from the file). My "other condition" is another file with a list of terms. I want to get the abstracts that contain those terms within the given primary keys.

My full-text search is something like this:

```
while(<FILE1>){
$PK = $_;
foreach $foo(@foo){
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
   SELECT value
     FROM value_table
    WHERE MATCH (column_text_indexed) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
}) AND primary_key=$PK;

$sth->execute(qq{+"$foo"});
}
}
```

where $PK is coming from the list of primary keys I already have.
$foo will be the list of the terms (condition 2) I am looking for.

Normally, I can run this query number of $PK times number of $foo. But I learned something about optimization by sub querying where I won't be running my query # $PK times # $foo. That will get rid of inner loop but will still form combination of every $PK with every term in file 2 that is @foo. Something like as follows:

```
while(<FILE1>){
$PK = $_;
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
   SELECT value
     FROM value_table
    WHERE MATCH (column_text_indexed) AGAINST (**SUB QUERYING HERE**)
}) AND primary_key=$PK;

$sth->execute(qq{+"$foo"});

}
```

Just I don't know how to do it. I may be wrong with the syntax. I want to know how to write code for full-text search as well as a subquery. I hope this will be efficient than querying directly the combinations. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a subquery. But you can still get rid of the inner loop by combining the match strings.

```
my $against = join ' ', map {qq/"$_"/} @foo;
while (my $PK = <FILE1>) {
    chomp $PK;

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
       SELECT value
         FROM value_table
        WHERE primary_key = ?
          # no '+' so it can match against at least one of the words in the list
          AND MATCH (column_text_indexed) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    });
    $sth->execute($PK, $against);
```

**Update**

I revised it and have completely removed the query from the loops.

```
my @primary_keys;
while (my $PK = <FILE1>) {
    chomp $PK;
    push @primary_keys, $PK;
}

my $PK_list = join ',', map {qq/'$_'/} @primary_keys;
my $against = join ' ', map {qq/"$_"/} @foo;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
   SELECT value
     FROM value_table
    # placeholders can only represent single scalar values so $PK_list can't be bound
    WHERE primary_key IN ($PK_list)
      # no '+' so it can match against at least one of the words in the list
      AND MATCH (column_text_indexed) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
});
$sth->execute($against);

# continue with fetching the rows
...;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I want to get rid of inner loop. But what I am really looking for is combination of every $PK with every term in file 2 which is @foo. Will it do this?

Comment: Does that mean you want to repeat the record for each term that it matches? It's best if you test this code to see if it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey stevenl, I think the first code works for me. But I have another concern. $against is not just a word but there also includes phrases. If you observe my code uses qq around phrases to find the match. How can I implement it here? I tried execute($PK, qq{"$against"}), but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: See if my adjustments work for you. I've added quotes around each value of `$PK_list` and `$against`. Note also that `$PK_list` probably won't work as a bind value with the `IN` clause, but this may have a performance cost if you need to execute this query multiple times.

Comment: This helps very much.I tried my best to validate the code.I think it works for me.But not being from computer science background I'm not confident if your code does what I want. I just want to confirm. You can tell me if I'm wrong. I have a list of PrimaryKeys(FILE1) that is mapped to abstracts in database. I have another file with some terms(FILE2). Now I want only those Keys from FILE1 which also have the terms(from FILE2) in the abstracts; the only abstracts which are linked to PrimaryKeys from FILE1.Thus I'm skipping inner loop from my code.I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Yes I believe it is doing what you want. But even for myself I would need to test to verify its correctness. Try creating a few test cases for yourself: generate different versions of FILE1 and FILE2, and see if the output is what you expect. Use these scenarios to try to make the code fail.

Comment: I am doing it but its taking much time. As I have around 58,00,000 records in FILE1. I would like to know is there any other way which can make this process fast. As said in the post by pseudocode.

Comment: Separate your accuracy and performance testing into different test cases. I don't think you actually need that much data to verify the accuracy, so scale down FILE1 size so you can verify correctness much more quickly.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I didn't mean that I'm doing this for accuracy. This whole thing works for me, absolutely correct. Now when I'm dealing with the actual data I'm facing the speed problem. So, I just want to know if it can be done faster. Because I will be working on such multiple FILE1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6221/discussion-between-stevenl-and-smandape)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks dodgy. I think you meant:

```
while(<FILE1>){
    $PK = $_;

    foreach $foo (@foo){

         my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
                     SELECT value
                     FROM value_table
                     WHERE MATCH (column_text_indexed)
                       AGAINST (**SUB QUERYING HERE**)
                     AND primary_key=$PK });           # '})' after AND clause

         $sth->execute(qq{ $foo });
     }
}
```

But why not make `$PK` an additional argument in this case (and use best practices)? :

```
while ( my $PK = <FILE1> ) {

    chomp $PK;  # Remove trailing newline

    foreach my $foo ( @foo ) {   # Lexical $foo

        my $sth = $dbh->prepare( qq{
                         SELECT value
                         FROM value_table
                         WHERE MATCH (column_text_indexed)
                           AGAINST (**SUB QUERYING HERE**)
                         AND primary_key=? });             # Extra placeholder

        $sth->execute( $foo, $PK );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I put my question in wrong sense. Basically I want to get rid of second loop. Still I want to use the combination of PK from file 1 with every term in file2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficiency I would recommend to use least database transactions and operations. So in this case I think the best option is to just get the abstract from the database based the primary key and then search for the terms in that abstract by doing simple string search in your pearl or any other standard language code. I am not very sure of the length of your list of terms. But if its possible you can save it in a standard data-structure like array or list. The same operation in database would definitely take lot more time. I am not that good with pearl syntax so I am writing the algorithm.

for all the terms in PK get the abstract as a string variable :

for each term in array/list: find the term in string variable containing abstract. If found add the PK to a new file.

continue with next pk.

if not found then continue next term in array/list.